# Plotting error with Survplot and xlim in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'm plotting an incidence curve using the survplot package in R. I'm using the xlim option to limit the x-axis of my graph from 0-28. However, when I do this the x-axis will always extend to 30. The maximum potential value I have in my data is 28. Is there a way I can trim the x-axis to 28 instead of 30?

Here is my code and an example of the graph with the extra x-axis.

```
survplot(Survobj, 
             ylim=c(0,10),
             xlim=c(0,28),
             ylab = "Cumulative Incidence, %", 
             conf=c("bands"),
             fun=function(x) {100*(1-x)}, 
             n.risk=FALSE,
             time.inc=1, 
             cex.n.risk=0.9)
```

I would attach an image, but I need 10 reputations points to do so (sorry!)

Comment: Even though you can't include an image directly in your post, you can paste a link to a URL where your picture is hosted. Also, please include a [minimum reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), otherwise there isn't much we can do to help.

Comment: Since the `survplot` package is not yet on CRAN, perhaps a good way to go if you can't figure it out is to contact [the developer](http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/staff/show-staff.php?id=742).

Comment: Based on the spelling of parameters, I suspect this is actually the `survplot` function from the `rms` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for `survplot.rms` (which has the same parameters as you are using and does exhibit the behavior you're describing) is base-R-grphics and it uses the `pretty` function to build the x-axis:

```
 pretty(c(0,28))
#[1]  0  5 10 15 20 25 30
```

So if you want to change its behavior you will need to hack the code. It's not that hard to hack R code, but it's unclear to me whether you are ready for that adventure since you didn't even name the package from which you got the function correctly. It is a fairly long function. Experience has taught me that I need to provide newbies with a turnkey solution rather than just telling them to add a parameter and find the sections in the code to tweak. Here's how to add a 'notpretty' parameter that is used to determine whether just the `max` or the `pretty` function is used on the `xlim` argument:

```
survplot2 <- function (fit, ..., xlim, ylim = if (loglog) c(-5, 1.5) else if (what == 
    "survival" & missing(fun)) c(0, 1), xlab, ylab, time.inc, 
    what = c("survival", "hazard"), type = c("tsiatis", "kaplan-meier"), 
    conf.type = c("log", "log-log", "plain", "none"), conf.int = FALSE, 
    conf = c("bands", "bars"), add = FALSE, label.curves = TRUE, 
    abbrev.label = FALSE, levels.only = FALSE, lty, lwd = par("lwd"), 
    col = 1, col.fill = gray(seq(0.95, 0.75, length = 5)), adj.subtitle = TRUE, 
    loglog = FALSE, fun, n.risk = FALSE, logt = FALSE, dots = FALSE, 
    dotsize = 0.003, grid = NULL, srt.n.risk = 0, sep.n.risk = 0.056, 
    adj.n.risk = 1, y.n.risk, cex.n.risk = 0.6, pr = FALSE,notpretty=FALSE) 
{
    what <- match.arg(what)
    polyg <- ordGridFun(grid = FALSE)$polygon
    ylim <- ylim
    type <- match.arg(type)
    conf.type <- match.arg(conf.type)
    conf <- match.arg(conf)
    opar <- par(c("mar", "xpd"))
    on.exit(par(opar))
    psmfit <- inherits(fit, "psm")
    if (what == "hazard" && !psmfit) 
        stop("what=\"hazard\" may only be used for fits from psm")
    if (what == "hazard" & conf.int > 0) {
        warning("conf.int may only be used with what=\"survival\"")
        conf.int <- FALSE
    }
    if (loglog) {
        fun <- function(x) logb(-logb(ifelse(x == 0 | x == 1, 
            NA, x)))
        use.fun <- TRUE
    }
    else if (!missing(fun)) {
        use.fun <- TRUE
        if (loglog) 
            stop("cannot specify loglog=T with fun")
    }
    else {
        fun <- function(x) x
        use.fun <- FALSE
    }
    if (what == "hazard" & loglog) 
        stop("may not specify loglog=T with what=\"hazard\"")
    if (use.fun | logt | what == "hazard") {
        dots <- FALSE
        grid <- NULL
    }
    cox <- inherits(fit, "cph")
    if (cox) {
        if (n.risk | conf.int > 0) 
            surv.sum <- fit$surv.summary
        exactci <- !(is.null(fit$x) | is.null(fit$y))
        ltype <- "s"
    }
    else {
        if (n.risk) 
            stop("the n.risk option applies only to fits from cph")
        exactci <- TRUE
        ltype <- "l"
    }
    par(xpd = NA)
    ciupper <- function(surv, d) ifelse(surv == 0, 0, pmin(1, 
        surv * exp(d)))
    cilower <- function(surv, d) ifelse(surv == 0, 0, surv * 
        exp(-d))
    labelc <- is.list(label.curves) || label.curves
    units <- fit$units
    if (missing(ylab)) {
        if (loglog) 
            ylab <- "log(-log Survival Probability)"
        else if (use.fun) 
            ylab <- ""
        else if (what == "hazard") 
            ylab <- "Hazard Function"
        else ylab <- "Survival Probability"
    }
    if (missing(xlab)) {
        if (logt) 
            xlab <- paste("log Survival Time in ", units, "s", 
                sep = "")
        else xlab <- paste(units, "s", sep = "")
    }
    maxtime <- fit$maxtime
    maxtime <- max(pretty(c(0, maxtime)))
    if (missing(time.inc)) 
        time.inc <- fit$time.inc
    if (missing(xlim)) 
        xlim <- if (logt) 
            logb(c(maxtime/100, maxtime))
        else c(0, maxtime)
    if (length(grid) && is.logical(grid)) 
        grid <- if (grid) 
            gray(0.8)
        else NULL
    if (is.logical(conf.int)) {
        if (conf.int) 
            conf.int <- 0.95
        else conf.int <- 0
    }
    zcrit <- qnorm((1 + conf.int)/2)
    xadj <- Predict(fit, type = "model.frame", np = 5, factors = rmsArgs(substitute(list(...))))
    info <- attr(xadj, "info")
    varying <- info$varying
    if (length(varying) > 1) 
        stop("cannot vary more than one predictor")
    adjust <- if (adj.subtitle) 
        info$adjust
    else NULL
    if (length(xadj)) {
        nc <- nrow(xadj)
        covpres <- TRUE
    }
    else {
        nc <- 1
        covpres <- FALSE
    }
    y <- if (length(varying)) 
        xadj[[varying]]
    else ""
    curve.labels <- NULL
    xd <- xlim[2] - xlim[1]
    if (n.risk & !add) {
        mar <- opar$mar
        if (mar[4] < 4) {
            mar[4] <- mar[4] + 2
            par(mar = mar)
        }
    }
    lty <- if (missing(lty)) 
        seq(nc + 1)[-2]
    else rep(lty, length = nc)
    col <- rep(col, length = nc)
    lwd <- rep(lwd, length = nc)
    i <- 0
    if (levels.only) 
        y <- gsub(".*=", "", y)
    abbrevy <- if (abbrev.label) 
        abbreviate(y)
    else y
    abbrevy <- if (is.factor(abbrevy)) 
        as.character(abbrevy)
    else format(abbrevy)
    if (labelc || conf == "bands") 
        curves <- vector("list", nc)
    for (i in 1:nc) {
        ci <- conf.int
        ay <- if (length(varying)) 
            xadj[[varying]]
        else ""
        if (covpres) {
            adj <- xadj[i, , drop = FALSE]
            w <- survest(fit, newdata = adj, fun = fun, what = what, 
                conf.int = ci, type = type, conf.type = conf.type)
        }
        else w <- survest(fit, fun = fun, what = what, conf.int = ci, 
            type = type, conf.type = conf.type)
        time <- w$time
        if (logt) 
            time <- logb(time)
        s <- !is.na(time) & (time >= xlim[1])
        surv <- w$surv
        if (is.null(ylim)) 
            ylim <- range(surv, na.rm = TRUE)
        stratum <- w$strata
        if (is.null(stratum)) 
            stratum <- 1
        if (!is.na(stratum)) {
            cl <- if (is.factor(ay)) 
                as.character(ay)
            else format(ay)
            curve.labels <- c(curve.labels, abbrevy[i])
            if (i == 1 & !add) {
                plot(time, surv, xlab = xlab, xlim = xlim, ylab = ylab, 
                  ylim = ylim, type = "n", axes = FALSE)
                mgp.axis(1, at = if (logt) 
                  pretty(xlim)
 # This is the line that was changed -----------------------
                else seq(xlim[1], if(notpretty){max(xlim)}else{max(pretty(xlim))}, time.inc), 
  #  end of modifications ------------------------
                  labels = TRUE)
                mgp.axis(2, at = pretty(ylim))
                if (!logt & (dots || length(grid))) {
                  xlm <- pretty(xlim)
                  xlm <- c(xlm[1], xlm[length(xlm)])
                  xp <- seq(xlm[1], xlm[2], by = time.inc)
                  yd <- ylim[2] - ylim[1]
                  if (yd <= 0.1) 
                    yi <- 0.01
                  else if (yd <= 0.2) 
                    yi <- 0.025
                  else if (yd <= 0.4) 
                    yi <- 0.05
                  else yi <- 0.1
                  yp <- seq(ylim[2], ylim[1] + if (n.risk && 
                    missing(y.n.risk)) 
                    yi
                  else 0, by = -yi)
                  if (dots) 
                    for (tt in xp) symbols(rep(tt, length(yp)), 
                      yp, circles = rep(dotsize, length(yp)), 
                      inches = dotsize, add = TRUE)
                  else abline(h = yp, v = xp, col = grid, xpd = FALSE)
                }
            }
            tim <- time[s]
            srv <- surv[s]
            if (conf.int > 0 && conf == "bands") {
                blower <- w$lower[s]
                bupper <- w$upper[s]
            }
            if (max(tim) > xlim[2]) {
                if (ltype == "s") {
                  s.last <- srv[tim <= xlim[2] + 1e-06]
                  s.last <- s.last[length(s.last)]
                  k <- tim < xlim[2]
                  tim <- c(tim[k], xlim[2])
                  srv <- c(srv[k], s.last)
                  if (conf.int > 0 && conf == "bands") {
                    low.last <- blower[time <= xlim[2] + 1e-06]
                    low.last <- low.last[length(low.last)]
                    up.last <- bupper[time <= xlim[2] + 1e-06]
                    up.last <- up.last[length(up.last)]
                    blower <- c(blower[k], low.last)
                    bupper <- c(bupper[k], up.last)
                  }
                }
                else tim[tim > xlim[2]] <- NA
            }
            if (conf != "bands") 
                lines(tim, srv, type = ltype, lty = lty[i], col = col[i], 
                  lwd = lwd[i])
            if (labelc || conf == "bands") 
                curves[[i]] <- list(tim, srv)
            if (pr) {
                zest <- rbind(tim, srv)
                dimnames(zest) <- list(c("Time", "Survival"), 
                  rep("", length(srv)))
                cat("\nEstimates for ", cl, "\n\n")
                print(zest, digits = 3)
            }
            if (conf.int > 0) {
                if (conf == "bands") {
                  polyg(x = c(tim, rev(tim)), y = c(blower, rev(bupper)), 
                    col = col.fill[i], type = ltype)
                }
                else {
                  if (exactci) {
                    tt <- seq(0, maxtime, time.inc)
                    v <- survest(fit, newdata = adj, times = tt, 
                      what = what, fun = fun, conf.int = ci, 
                      type = type, conf.type = conf.type)
                    tt <- v$time
                    ss <- v$surv
                    lower <- v$lower
                    upper <- v$upper
                    if (!length(ylim)) 
                      ylim <- range(ss, na.rm = TRUE)
                    if (logt) 
                      tt <- logb(ifelse(tt == 0, NA, tt))
                  }
                  else {
                    tt <- as.numeric(dimnames(surv.sum)[[1]])
                    if (logt) 
                      tt <- logb(tt)
                    ss <- surv.sum[, stratum, "Survival"]^exp(w$linear.predictors)
                    se <- surv.sum[, stratum, "std.err"]
                    ss <- fun(ss)
                    lower <- fun(cilower(ss, zcrit * se))
                    upper <- fun(ciupper(ss, zcrit * se))
                    ss[is.infinite(ss)] <- NA
                    lower[is.infinite(lower)] <- NA
                    upper[is.infinite(upper)] <- NA
                  }
                  tt <- tt + xd * (i - 1) * 0.01
                  errbar(tt, ss, upper, lower, add = TRUE, lty = lty[i], 
                    col = col[i])
                }
            }
            if (n.risk) {
                if (length(Y <- fit$y)) {
                  tt <- seq(max(0, xlim[1]), min(maxtime, xlim[2]), 
                    by = time.inc)
                  ny <- ncol(Y)
                  if (!length(str <- fit$Strata)) 
                    Y <- Y[, ny - 1]
                  else Y <- Y[unclass(str) == unclass(stratum), 
                    ny - 1]
                  nrisk <- rev(cumsum(table(cut(-Y, sort(unique(-c(tt, 
                    range(Y) + c(-1, 1))))))[-length(tt) - 1]))
                }
                else {
                  if (is.null(surv.sum)) 
                    stop("you must use surv=T or y=T in fit to use n.risk=T")
                  tt <- as.numeric(dimnames(surv.sum)[[1]])
                  l <- (tt >= xlim[1]) & (tt <= xlim[2])
                  tt <- tt[l]
                  nrisk <- surv.sum[l, stratum, 2]
                }
                tt[1] <- xlim[1]
                yd <- ylim[2] - ylim[1]
                if (missing(y.n.risk)) 
                  y.n.risk <- ylim[1]
                yy <- y.n.risk + yd * (nc - i) * sep.n.risk
                nri <- nrisk
                nri[tt > xlim[2]] <- NA
                text(tt[1], yy, nri[1], cex = cex.n.risk, adj = adj.n.risk, 
                  srt = srt.n.risk)
                text(tt[-1], yy, nri[-1], cex = cex.n.risk, adj = 1)
                text(xlim[2] + xd * 0.025, yy, adj = 0, curve.labels[i], 
                  cex = cex.n.risk)
            }
        }
    }
    if (conf == "bands") 
        for (i in 1:length(y)) lines(curves[[i]][[1]], curves[[i]][[2]], 
            type = ltype, lty = lty[i], col = col[i], lwd = lwd[i])
    if (labelc) 
        labcurve(curves, curve.labels, type = ltype, lty = lty, 
            col. = col, lwd = lwd, opts = label.curves)
    if (length(adjust)) 
        title(sub = paste("Adjusted to:", adjust), adj = 0, cex = 0.6)
    invisible(list(adjust = adjust, curve.labels = curve.labels))
}
environment(survplot2) <- environment(rms:::survplot.rms)
```

Tested with the first example in `rms::survplot` using `xlim=c(0,26)` and `xlim=c(0,28)`. Needed to assign the environment because otherwise you get this error:

```
Error in Predict(fit, type = "model.frame", np = 5, 
                           factors = rmsArgs(substitute(list(...)))) : 
  could not find function "rmsArgs"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. I'm getting the following error:

Error in UseMethod("survest") : 
  no applicable method for 'survest' applied to an object of class "c('npsurv', 'survfit')"

Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: I'm not sure what we can say. The error is coming from data and code that you have not provided. You expect too much of our mind-reading capacities.

Comment: How did you get hold of the code for `survplot.rms`? When I type `survplot` it just tells me `usemethod("suvplot")` instead of giving the code as it would do for other functions

Comment: I think it is part of the ‘rms’ package and one just types the name of the function without parentheses. https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/rms/html/survplot.html  I don’t know if the function is still base graphics. Harrell converted some of the plot routines to ggplot2.